# Intel server board support 2 types of RAM sticks - is it possible?

Tags: motherboard, ddr2, ddr

While trying to figure out what to do with an old Intel server I have. On the Intel site spec page for the server board: [SR1435VP2](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/server/sr1435vp2/) it is mentioned that it can support both [DDR and DDR2 400](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/cs-012671.htm).

I ask: How is that possible?

Can there be 2 versions for the board?

Comment: No.  While there likely is 2 revisions of the same board, it would be purely surface changes, not changing what memory it can support.  How this is possible is simple they design the board to support either type.  Clearly its not possible to use BOTH are the sametime.

Comment: just as I figured. DANG Intel, why can't they just give a V# to the board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [specifications on Intel's site](http://www.intel.com/cd/channel/reseller/apac/eng/products/server/systems/discontinued/sr1435vp2/feature/index.htm#motherboard), there are two different revisions of this board: SE7320VP2 (supporting DDR-266/333) and SE7320VP2D2 (supporting DDR2-400).